# Bootstrap custom layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2 and want to implement a layout as below;

[image]

How do I update the code below to achieve the same (basically right align the Edit button with the label Notes);

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div><label for="Notes" class="control-label" style="text-align:left">Notes</label></div>
        <div><button class='btn btn-small editNotes globalNotes' src='' title='Edit notes'><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</button></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">
        <div class="thumbnail clearfix" style="width:455px; height: 190px; overflow: auto">
            <span id="notesPanel"><pre id="notesTxt" style="border:none; background: none; display:inline;">new</pre></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle? that would give us a better sense of what you've already got and enable us to modify - give you a solution :)

Comment: in addition, just a comment regarding your meta data. You should'nt really use inline styles i.e `style=""`. Use the proper syntax, it enables us to see your code more clearly.

Comment: it is actually part of a web app...so would be difficult for me...i have pulled out the relevant code and listed here...

Comment: would this be your answer? http://jsfiddle.net/LKtu6/ if so let me know and i'll convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add class defined in bootstrap i.e `pull-left`, `pull-right`

```
<label for="Notes" class="control-label pull-left">Notes</label>  
<button class='btn btn-small editNotes globalNotes pull-right' src='' title='Edit notes'><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit</button>
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xBG97/)

Comment: Thx and should i give a px width for the entire row..Ideally i would like it to span the entire available width

Comment: yes you can give but you should use class defined by bootstrap for responsive view. check it out here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/